# How to configure windows salt minion for rabbitmq module?

Tags: rabbitmq, salt-stack

We're running several windows server with RabbitMQ and salt minion on it. Our aim is to control and configure RabbitMQ via salt.

The first problem with which we had been confronted was

```
'rabbitmq' __virtual__ returned false
```

After digging in the source code, we solved this by adding the rabbitmq sbin folder to the PATH.

The next error

```
 ERROR: password is a required argument for runas on Windows
```

was pretty easy to solve. Just add a runas="" after your call and it's fine.

... or not

```
ERROR: Unable to run command '['rabbitmqctl', 'status']' with the context '{'timeout': None, 'with_communicate': True, 'shell': False, 'bg': False, 'stderr': -2, 'env': {'TMP': 'C:\\Windows\\TEMP', 'COMPUTERNAME': 'TMS-230017010', 'USERDOMAIN': 'WORKGROUP', 'PSMODULEPATH': 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules\\;c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\110\\Tools\\PowerShell\\Modules\\', 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files', 'PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER': 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 44 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel', 'PROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files', 'PROCESSOR_REVISION': '2c02', 'SYSTEMROOT': 'C:\\Windows', 'PATH': '%programfiles%\\rabbitmq server\\rabbitmq_server-3.6.1\\sbin;c:\\programdata\\oracle\\java\\javapath;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\system32\\wbem;C:\\Windows\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0;c:\\program files (x86)\\microsoft sql server\\110\\tools\\binn;c:\\program files\\microsoft sql server\\110\\tools\\binn;c:\\program files\\microsoft sql server\\110\\dts\\binn;c:\\program files (x86)\\microsoft sql server\\110\\tools\\binn\\managementstudio;c:\\program files (x86)\\microsoft sql server\\110\\dts\\binn;C:\\Program Files\\rabbitmq server\\rabbitmq_server-3.6.1\\sbin;C:\\salt\\bin\\lib\\site-packages\\pywin32_system32;/bin;/sbin;/usr/bin;/usr/sbin;/usr/local/bin;C:\\salt\\bin\\lib\\site-packages\\pywin32_system32', 'PROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)', 'TEMP': 'C:\\Windows\\TEMP', 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files', 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE': 'AMD64', 'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\\ProgramData', 'LOCALAPPDATA': 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Local', 'PROGRAMW6432': 'C:\\Program Files', 'USERNAME': 'TMS-230017010$', 'COMSPEC': 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', 'PROGRAMDATA': 'C:\\ProgramData', 'PATHEXT': '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC', 'FP_NO_HOST_CHECK': 'NO', 'WINDIR': 'C:\\Windows', 'APPDATA': 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Roaming', 'SYSTEMDRIVE': 'C:', 'PYTHONHOME': '', 'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS': '4', 'PROCESSOR_LEVEL': '6', 'ERLANG_HOME': 'C:\\Program Files\\erl7.3', 'COMMONPROGRAMW6432': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files', 'OS': 'Windows_NT', 'PUBLIC': 'C:\\Users\\Public', 'USERPROFILE': 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile'}, 'stdout': -1, 'stdin': None, 'cwd': 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile'}', reason: [Error 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

The context pretty printed:

```
{
    'timeout': None,
    'with_communicate': True,
    'shell': False,
    'bg': False,
    'stderr': -2,
    'env': {
        'TMP': 'C: \\Windows\\TEMP',
        'COMPUTERNAME': 'TMS-230017010',
        'USERDOMAIN': 'WORKGROUP',
        'PSMODULEPATH': 'C: \\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules\\;c: \\ProgramFiles(x86)\\MicrosoftSQLServer\\110\\Tools\\PowerShell\\Modules\\',
        'COMMONPROGRAMFILES': 'C: \\ProgramFiles\\CommonFiles',
        'PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER': 'Intel64Family6Model44Stepping2,GenuineIntel',
        'PROGRAMFILES': 'C: \\ProgramFiles',
        'PROCESSOR_REVISION': '2c02',
        'SYSTEMROOT': 'C: \\Windows',
        'PATH': '%programfiles%\\rabbitmqserver\\rabbitmq_server-3.6.1\\sbin;c: \\programdata\\oracle\\java\\javapath;C: \\Windows\\system32;C: \\Windows;C: \\Windows\\system32\\wbem;C: \\Windows\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0;c: \\programfiles(x86)\\microsoftsqlserver\\110\\tools\\binn;c: \\programfiles\\microsoftsqlserver\\110\\tools\\binn;c: \\programfiles\\microsoftsqlserver\\110\\dts\\binn;c: \\programfiles(x86)\\microsoftsqlserver\\110\\tools\\binn\\managementstudio;c: \\programfiles(x86)\\microsoftsqlserver\\110\\dts\\binn;C: \\ProgramFiles\\rabbitmqserver\\rabbitmq_server-3.6.1\\sbin;C: \\salt\\bin\\lib\\site-packages\\pywin32_system32;/bin;/sbin;/usr/bin;/usr/sbin;/usr/local/bin;C: \\salt\\bin\\lib\\site-packages\\pywin32_system32',
        'PROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C: \\ProgramFiles(x86)',
        'TEMP': 'C: \\Windows\\TEMP',
        'COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C: \\ProgramFiles(x86)\\CommonFiles',
        'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE': 'AMD64',
        'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C: \\ProgramData',
        'LOCALAPPDATA': 'C: \\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Local',
        'PROGRAMW6432': 'C: \\ProgramFiles',
        'USERNAME': 'TMS-230017010$',
        'COMSPEC': 'C: \\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe',
        'PROGRAMDATA': 'C: \\ProgramData',
        'PATHEXT': '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC',
        'FP_NO_HOST_CHECK': 'NO',
        'WINDIR': 'C: \\Windows',
        'APPDATA': 'C: \\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Roaming',
        'SYSTEMDRIVE': 'C: ',
        'PYTHONHOME': '',
        'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS': '4',
        'PROCESSOR_LEVEL': '6',
        'ERLANG_HOME': 'C: \\ProgramFiles\\erl7.3',
        'COMMONPROGRAMW6432': 'C: \\ProgramFiles\\CommonFiles',
        'OS': 'Windows_NT',
        'PUBLIC': 'C: \\Users\\Public',
        'USERPROFILE': 'C: \\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile'
    },
    'stdout': -1,
    'stdin': None,
    'cwd': 'C: \\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile'
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to solve this problem?

---

**EDIT:**
The output from test.versions_report

```
    Salt Version:
           Salt: 2016.3.1

Dependency Versions:
           cffi: 1.6.0
       cherrypy: 5.3.0
       dateutil: 2.5.3
          gitdb: 0.6.4
      gitpython: 2.0.2
          ioflo: 1.5.3
         Jinja2: 2.8
        libgit2: Not Installed
        libnacl: Not Installed
       M2Crypto: Not Installed
           Mako: 1.0.4
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.4.7
   mysql-python: Not Installed
      pycparser: 2.14
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
         pygit2: Not Installed
         Python: 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:24:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
   python-gnupg: 0.3.8
         PyYAML: 3.11
          PyZMQ: 15.2.0
           RAET: Not Installed
          smmap: 0.9.0
        timelib: 0.2.4
        Tornado: 4.3
            ZMQ: 4.1.2

System Versions:
           dist:
        machine: AMD64
        release: 8
         system: Windows
        version: 8 6.2.9200 SP0 Multiprocessor Free
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of  `salt <windows minion> test.versions_report`?

Comment: @Utah_Dave I've added the output as edit

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this and it would be helpful if we had the exact CLI command you executed as well as the output, but I'm guessing that this error you saw:

```
ERROR: password is a required argument for runas on Windows
```

means that you need to add a `password` argument to your command

```
salt < the rest of your command > password='<my password>'
```

Be aware that running that salt command on your linux salt master will be logged, along with that password. We might need to modify the rabbitmq stuff to work better on Windows. I'm not sure if it was originally written with Windows in mind.

Comment: I run `salt <windwos minion> rabbitmq.status`. The problem `ERROR: password is a required argument for runas on Windows`  can be solved by providing `runas=''`, too.

Comment: I've tried `salt <windwos minon> rabbitmq.status password='<topsecret>'` and get the following error `ERROR executing 'rabbitmq.status': The following keyword arguments are not valid: password=<topsecret>`